# Building ros1_bridge fails in Docker container (Noetic & Foxy)

Tags: ros, build-from-source

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am trying to build `ros1_bridge` under Docker with Noetic as the ROS1 distro and Foxy as the ROS2 distro. I have tried many different approaches but none seemed to work, or better, they all ended with the same error (described bellow).

For this post I tried to take similar steps as in [here](https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge/issues/261). I am trying to build a Docker image using the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM ros:foxy-ros1-bridge

RUN apt-get update \
  && apt-get install -y ssh \
    build-essential \
    gcc \
    g++ \
    gdb \
    clang \
    cmake \
    rsync \
    nano \
    tar \
    python3 \
    ros-foxy-launch* \
  && apt-get clean

ENTRYPOINT ["/ros_entrypoint.sh"]

WORKDIR "/home/workspace"

CMD /bin/bash
```

Once the image is build I run the following commands (inside the container):

Clone the repo at the appropriate brench

```
git clone --single-branch --branch foxy https://github.com/ros2/ros1_bridge src/ros1_bridge
```

Build everything but the `ros1_bridge`

```
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-skip ros1_bridge
```

Source both environments

```
source /opt/ros/noetic/setup.bash
source /opt/ros/foxy/setup.bash
```

and finally

```
colcon build --symlink-install --packages-select ros1_bridge --cmake-force-configure --event-handlers console_direct+
```

After a bit (almost 20 minutes) the compilation stops with the following error:

```
[ 98%] Linking CXX shared library libros1_bridge.so
[Processing: ros1_bridge]
[Processing: ros1_bridge]
[Processing: ros1_bridge]
[Processing: ros1_bridge]
[Processing: ros1_bridge]
[Processing: ros1_bridge]
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/build.make:5157: libros1_bridge.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'libros1_bridge.so'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:260: CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
--- stderr: ros1_bridge
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 9 [Killed]
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/build.make:5157: libros1_bridge.so] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'libros1_bridge.so'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:260: CMakeFiles/ros1_bridge.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:141: all] Error 2
---
Failed   <<< ros1_bridge [19min 22s, exited with code 2]

Summary: 0 packages finished [19min 22s]
  1 package failed: ros1_bridge
  1 package had stderr output: ros1_bridge
```

Since the error is not really descriptive, I don't know how to proceed from here and I need some help. Are there any other flags besides `--event-handlers console_direct+` that I can add to `colcon` for an even more verbose output?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/363335/building-ros1_bridge-fails-in-docker-container-(noetic-&-foxy)/) by [tgaspar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31049/tgaspar/) on ROS Answers with karma: 13 on 2020-10-13

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I ran the same steps and could finish compilation successfully.

Is it possible you are running out of memory? The linking phase of this pkg seems to be quite heavy on the memory.

---

Originally posted by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) with karma: 651 on 2020-11-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [tgaspar](https://answers.ros.org/users/31049/tgaspar/) on 2020-11-04**:
That was it, thank you! I ran the whole thing again on a different machine and same as you had no issues with building. The fact that memory was an issue never crossed my mind also because there were no hints from `colcon` regarding this.

**Comment by [Victor Lopez](https://answers.ros.org/users/395/victor-lopez/) on 2020-11-04**:
It's just that the linker dies. Glad I could help.